# How to make datatable row or cell clickable?

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I'm working on a history development of a particular user and I want it to be done with dataTables. However, I cannot find the way with which I can make my row or a particular cell clickable. I need to open separate links with the separate clicks for particular row. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance !!!

Edited:: If I click on a row, I need all the data of the row, which is not a problem. I can do that. What I need to know is to make an $.ajax() request with that particular row data. I think this will do. However, it would be great to know how to open a link in a new tab on row click.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dataSet = [
        []
    ];
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "webservices/view_patient_medical_history.php",
        async: false,
        //data: {'log_id': data},
        success: function(response) {
            dataSet = JSON.parse(response);
        }
    });

    //   var dataSet_arr = jQuery.makeArray(dataSet['responseText']);

    $('#patient_medical_history').DataTable({
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [{
            title: "Patient ID",
            class: "center"
        }, {
            title: "Current Medications",
            class: "center"
        }, {
            title: "Allergies",
            class: "center"
        }, {
            title: "Diabetes",
            class: "center"
        }, {
            title: "Asthma",
            class: "center"
        }, {
            title: "Arthritis",
            class: "center"
        }, {
            title: "High Blood Pressure",
            class: "center"
        }, {
            title: "Kidney Problem",
            class: "center"
        }, {
            title: "Liver Problem",
            class: "center"
        }, {
            title: "Heart Problem",
            class: "center"
        }, {
            title: "Other Problems",
            class: "center"
        }, {
            title: "Present Problem",
            class: "center"
        }, {
            title: "Last Updated",
            class: "center"
        }],
        "scrollX": true,
        //"paging": false,
        "info": false,
        //"lengthMenu": false,
        dom: 'lBfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]


        /*"paging": false,
        "info": false,
         dom: 'Bfrtip',
         buttons: [
            'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]*/
    });

    $('th').css("white-space", "nowrap");
});
```

Comment: ` I need to open separate links with the separate clicks for particular row.` so what value are you using to open different links? are you fetching from thw row itself?

Comment: I'm sorry, mate. Didn't bother to add unnecessary codes as almost everyone is used to the common implementations of datatables. All I want with those basic features is to make rows clickable. 

Anyway...here is a code of my demo tanle. I want rows to be clicked.

Comment: I've edited my question with the code of the basic structure of my table. Now, I need those rows clickable.

Comment: Actually...if I could send a $_GET or $_POST request to a php using specific row or cell data, that would be enough... Reddy

Comment: what if i want to make each cell of a particular column clickable . On click of that cell i want to make an ajax call . Please suggest some way to get it working

Answer (score 56, accepted):

To activate click on cell you must use a delegated event handler - this will work on any dataTable :

```js
$('.dataTable').on('click', 'tbody td', function() {

  //get textContent of the TD
  console.log('TD cell textContent : ', this.textContent)

  //get the value of the TD using the API 
  console.log('value by API : ', table.cell({ row: this.parentNode.rowIndex, column : this.cellIndex }).data());
})
```

Retrieving data of a clicked row can be done by

```js
$('.dataTable').on('click', 'tbody tr', function() {
  console.log('API row values : ', table.row(this).data());
})
```

If you want to send row content via AJAX you should transform the array to an object, and then include it as `data` :

```js
$('.dataTable').on('click', 'tbody tr', function() {
  var data = table.row(this).data().map(function(item, index) {
     var r = {}; r['col'+index]=item; return r;
  })
  //now use AJAX with data, which is on the form [ { col1 : value, col2: value ..}]
  $.ajax({
    data: data,
    url: url,
    success: function(response) {
       ...
    }
})
```

If you just want a plain link in a cell with `target: _blank` you can use `render` :

```js
columns: [
  { title: "Patient ID", class: "center", render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
     return '<a href="showdata/id?'+data+'" target=_blank>Show patient</a>'
  }
},
```

Comment: I think you forgot to mention how to set the variable `table`

Comment: You can use this for the variable `table`:

`var table = $('.dataTable').DataTable();`

Comment: This does not seem to work for me. The "table.row..."Always comes back undefined. The table is recognized and so are the rows (i.g. table[0].rows)

Comment: A little extra: for the cell click handler, `this._DT_CellIndex` is an object with the row ID and column index.

Comment: The example for a plain link in a cell worked for me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

First make sure you change the code of your dataTable initialization to save into a variable like this

```
var oPatientMedicalHistory = $('#patient_medical_history').DataTable({
   //your stuff
});
```

Then you can assign a click event to all the rows like this

**EDIT:** As Pointed out by Gyrocode.com, we should use delegated event handler as the tr's are created dynamically as we page. So The code should look like.

```
$('#patient_medical_history tbody').on('dblclick','tr', function() {
    var currentRowData = oPatientMedicalHistory.row(this).data();
    // alert(currentRowData[0]) // wil give you the value of this clicked row and first index (td)
    //your stuff goes here
});
```

This must help you out.

Comment: thanks a lot, mate. This will help me to get on with it for sure. However, I'm quite new to datatables. Can you tell me if currentRowData[0] gives me the clicked row, then what will currentRowData[1] return ? and if I wish to get the value of a particular cell of that row, what might the process be ?

Comment: `currentRowData`  = array of values of the current row
`currentRowData[0]` = the first index of the array, that means the first td value of the row, similarly `currentRowData[1]` will give you second td value

Comment: This will only work for rows on the first page because DataTables creates `tr` nodes dynamically. You need to use delegated event handler, for example `$('#patient_medical_history tbody').on('dblclick', 'tr', function() {`

Comment: @Gyrocode.com Thank you for reminding me about this. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an eventhandler on click to cells(td) of your datatable and you have to define the action what you want to process in that eventhandler.

[datatables](https://www.datatables.net)

is a great source to have a look over and play around.

Answer (score 1):

We are using:

```
  rowCallback: function (row: Node /*, data: any[] | Object, index: number */) {

    // Intercept clicking of datatable links to avoid a full page refresh
    $('a', row).click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      // const href = $(this).attr('href')
      // parent.router.navigate([href])
    })

    // Navigate using anchor in cell to make entire cell clickable
    $('td', row).click(function (/* e */) {
      const anchor = $(this).find('a:first')[0]
      if (anchor) {
        const href = $(anchor).attr('href')
        parent.router.navigate([href])
      }
    })

    return row
  }
```

Not sure this is the best approach, but it does the job.

Apologies: this is TypeScript, but it's dead simple to convert to JS.

Answer (score 1):

on my side, using `row: this.parentNode.rowIndex` didn't worked.  I used `this.parentNode` instead and worked like a charm