# Create link with JQuery data tables during server-side processing

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am building a document management system. 
What I want to achieve is that when a user clicks a row, it will download the file, I have the file path in my json response.

Here's how the ajax request response looks like

```
[{
   created_at: "2017-12-14 00:30:30"
   directory_id: 1
   file_author: "Me"
   file_date: "0000-00-00"
   file_name: "Test"
   file_number: "000111"
   file_password: "12345"
   file_path: "files/5a31c62607871.pdf"
   id: 1
   scanned_date: "0000-00-00"
   updated_at: "2017-12-14 00:30:30"
 }, 
 {
   created_at: "2017-12-14 00:30:30"
   directory_id: 1
   file_author: "Me"
   file_date: "0000-00-00"
   file_name: "Test 2"
   file_number: "000333"
   file_password: "22558"
   file_path: "files/5a31c62607871.pdf"
   id: 1
   scanned_date: "0000-00-00"
   updated_at: "2017-12-14 00:30:30"
 }]
```

and this is how I process the json response from my backend to display in my data table.

```
$.ajax({
        url : '/get-files/'+id,
        type : 'get',
        success : function(response){
            var er = response.docs;     
            var data = jQuery.map(er, function(el, i) {
                return [[el.file_number, el.file_name, el.file_date, el.scanned_date, el.file_author]];
            });

            $('.data-table').DataTable({
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                "ordering": false,
                "pageLength": 100,
                "aaData": data,
                "aoColumns": [
                    { "sTitle": "Document No." },
                    { "sTitle": "Document Name" },
                    { "sTitle": "Date" },
                    { "sTitle": "Scanned Date" },
                    { "sTitle": "Author" },
                ],

            })
        }
    })
```

Comment: You probably want to have a look at the select event. https://datatables.net/reference/event/select

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make datatable row or cell clickable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35547647/how-to-make-datatable-row-or-cell-clickable)