# Add click event to datatable cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I'm trying to add a click event to a dynamically created a datatabe. So this is my js :

```
   $('#report-table').dataTable({
        "proccessing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            url: '@Url.Action("Get","Controller")',
            type: 'GET'

        },
       "columns": [
           { "data": "Name" },
                { "data": "Date" }, //lest say I want to add a click event here ???
                { "data": "sName", render: myRender }// I tried render but this is rendered without waiting on click function
        ]

    });
```

and this is my table for example :

```
<tr role="row" class="odd">
<td class="sorting_1">A Test</td>
<td class="aaaa">2/13/2020 3:34:40 PM</td> //lets say I want to fire a click event when I click the .aaaa class
<td>
    <a  asp-route-fileid="55555555" asp-action="Download5"><img src="img/download.svg" height="30" width="30"></a>
</td>
```

Let's say I want to fire a click event when I click the .aaaa class.

Can anyone please give me an idea? Can I do this?
I'm stucked right here. Any idea would be apprecciated very very much :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make datatable row or cell clickable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35547647/how-to-make-datatable-row-or-cell-clickable)

Comment: No because I want to click a specific cell, not all the row. A specific cell with a specific class @Kurt

Comment: You should just be able to change the selector. Instead of the generic `tbody td` you could do something like `.yourClass`.

Comment: No @Kurt . I already tried that. All the td come formated from the db. If I try what you say ofcourse it would not work.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include things you've tried? That will prevent replies from just suggesting what you've already done. It doesn't matter where the data comes from, you can still attach events to it. Just make sure that you're attaching them as it mentions in that link, with `on('click', '.yourClass', function() {...})`

Comment: lol @user6854465 .. Just NO man, that's not the answer... but thanks for trying though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this, for more check this [forum](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/32872/call-function-on-cell-button-click) :

```
$('#report-table').on('click', 'td.className', function (e) {
    // your code to do something
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `render` use `className` to add a class to the cell

```
   "columns": [
        { "data": "Name" },
        { 
            "data": "Date",
            "className": "your-class"
        },
        { "data": "sName" }
   ]
```

then put an on click event handler on your class

```
$('#report-table').on('click', '.your-class', function() {
    //function code here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("tr[role='row']").on('click',()=> {
    alert($(this).find('td.aaaa').text());
});
```